# how to display form at windows 8 homescreen

Tags: python, vb.net, winforms, windows-8, microsoft-metro

How would I get a Windows form to show up on not only the desktop but also the Windows 8 metro start screen? I know it's possible because the on-screen keyboard does this:

[image]

If you could tell me how to do this in VB.net or Python that would be great, but I'm fine with any other common language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in a Google search. This time I included task manager as part of the search, and I got the appropriate results.

[How to make Windows 8 desktop apps shown in Metro UI (like Task Manager)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873323/how-to-make-windows-8-desktop-apps-shown-in-metro-ui-like-task-manager)

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed one thing, the app which provides "Always on Top" option, we can open the app on top of Start screen. See the below image you can also open task manager on top of Start screen. Here's how you can provide "Always on Top" in Windows form app & python app, `though not sure for python as I am .NET guy :)`

[Keeping a Windows Form on Top - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984361(v=vs.71).aspx)

[How can I ensure that the application windows is always on top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678966/how-can-i-ensure-that-the-application-windows-is-always-on-top)

[How to make python window run as "Always On Top"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482565/how-to-make-python-window-run-as-always-on-top)

[image].

Comment: Thanks! Also I didn't know I could use Task Manager in the start screen and that's pretty useful.

Comment: Unfortunately, all of the code supplied makes a window topmost within the desktop, and does not duplicate the Task Manager's "Always on top" feature.